# Is there a way that I can make a LINQ .contains work independent of case?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am using this LINQ expression:

```
phrases = await db.Phrases
      .Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English))
```

Is there a way that I can modify this so it will find rows with words that contain the options.English phrase even if the case is different?

Comment: @GiladGreen reopen?

Comment: @GiladGreen Yes, it is.  That question has a few bad answers, but they're not all bad.